# AWS Cognito ConfirmForgotPassword invalid request

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use the ConfirmForgotPassword call with C# for AWS Cognito. When using the code below all I get is an exception "Request does not contain valid parameters" with no additional information.

Is there any way to find out what the invalid parameter is?

```
using (var cognito = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(AWS_AccessKey, AWS_SecretKey, AWSRegion))
{
    ConfirmForgotPasswordRequest confirmForgotPasswordRequest = new ConfirmForgotPasswordRequest();
    confirmForgotPasswordRequest.Username = userName;
    confirmForgotPasswordRequest.ClientId = clientId;
    confirmForgotPasswordRequest.Password = password;
    confirmForgotPasswordRequest.ConfirmationCode = confirmationCode;
    ConfirmForgotPasswordResponse confirmForgotPasswordResponse = new ConfirmForgotPasswordResponse();
    try
    {
        confirmForgotPasswordResponse = await cognito.ConfirmForgotPasswordAsync(confirmForgotPasswordRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // Raises exception "Request does not contain valid parameters"
    }
    
}
```

I'm not sure if the secret hash parameter is required, I have tried it with this code for the same result

```
confirmForgotPasswordRequest.SecretHash = HmacSha256(userName + clientId, clientSecret);

private string HmacSha256(string message, string secret)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 cryptographer = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(keyBytes);

    byte[] bytes = cryptographer.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to hash the code, you should send the exact code emailed to the user's confirmed email address after the ForgotPasswordAsync method is called.

Usually InvalidParameter exception means the ClientId is incorrect. If it were the code or the password, you would get [a different type of exception](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/MCognitoIdentityProviderConfirmForgotPasswordAsyncConfirmForgotPasswordRequestCancellationToken.html).

What does the Message property of the Exception say? If it is the ClientId causing the problem, you might see something like this:

```
"2 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'clientId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\w+]+; Value '' at 'clientId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1"
```